# Entity Framework group by memory collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an `Items` table with columns `Id`, `Code` and `Amount`.

There is an *in-memory* collection that has Code-Phase value pairs: `T100 - 1`, `L100 - 1`, `T200 - 2`... multiple codes can map to same phase number.

Getting the totals per code is simple.

```
 var totals = db.Items.GroupBy(x => x.Code)
                      .Select(x => new
                      {
                        Code = x.Key,
                        Total = x.Sum(y => y.Amount),
                      });
```

Is it possible to have a query in EF that finds the total amounts by phase number?

I know that combining in memory collections and EF `IQuerable` is not possible in general. I was hoping to do this without converting the DbSet to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: How many pairs do you have?

Comment: There are about 1 million items, 1000 codes mapped to phases numbers from 1 to 20.

Comment: Use SQL then, Or you can use third party extension which works temporary tables.

Answer (score -1):

You need to load query's result first:

```
var totals = db.Items.GroupBy(x => x.Code)
                      .Select(x => new
                      {
                        Code = x.Key,
                        Total = x.Sum(y => y.Amount),
                      }).ToList();
```

Then perform further calculation combining 'totals' with the Code-Phase collection:

```
class CodePhase {
    public string Code; public int Phase;
    public CodePhase(string code, int phase) { Code = code; Phase = phase; }
}

class SumItemPerCode {
    public string Code; public int Total;
    public SumItemPerCode(string code, int total) { Code = code; Total = total; }
}

List<SumItemPerCode> totals = [ new ("T100", 11), new("L100", 12), new("T200", 21)];
List<CodePhase> codephases = [new("T100", 1), new("L100", 1), new("T200", 2)];
var ct = totals.Join(codephases, o => o.Code, i => i.Code, (o, i) => new { i.Phase, o.Total })
    .GroupBy(g => g.Phase).Select(s => new { Pahse = s.Key, Total = s.Sum(y => y.Total) }).ToList();
foreach (var a in ct) Console.WriteLine(a);

-->

{ Pahse = 1, Total = 23 }
{ Pahse = 2, Total = 21 }
```

Comment: How is it going?